# Table with different number of columns after some rows

Tags: tables, columns, cell

I want to create a table with different number of columns after a specific row. This is what I've accomplished so far:

```
  \begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{ |p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|} 

\rowcolor[HTML]{e6e8e9} 
 \hline
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 & cell4 & cell5 & cell6  & cell7 & cell8\\  \hline
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 & cell4 & cell5 & cell6  & cell7 & cell8 \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{e6e8e9} 
cell1 & cell2 & cell3 & cell4 & cell5 & cell6  & cell7  \\ \hline
cell1 & cell2 & cell3 & cell4 & cell5 & cell6  & cell7  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

[image]

It also doesn't show the cell lines properly. When I try do add a caption, I'll always get an error.

Comment: A caption applies to a float like a figure or table, not to general text such as a tabular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stack `tabular`s vertically with a different number of columns. It will be easier to use `tabularx` if you want all tables to have the same width. `\nointerlineskip` prevents from adding an extra line skip.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tabularx}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*8{X|}}
        \rowcolor[HTML]{e6e8e9} 
        \hline
        cell1 & cell2 & cell3 & cell4 & cell5 & cell6  & cell7 & cell8 \\\hline
        cell1 & cell2 & cell3 & cell4 & cell5 & cell6  & cell7 & cell8 \\\hline
    \end{tabularx}
    
    \nointerlineskip
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| *7{X|}}
        \rowcolor[HTML]{e6e8e9} 
        cell1 & cell2 & cell3 & cell4 & cell5 & cell6  & cell7  \\\hline
        cell1 & cell2 & cell3 & cell4 & cell5 & cell6  & cell7  \\\hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Minor nit-pick: There's no point to execute `\centering` after `\begin{center}`, right?

Comment: @Mico Thanks for that. It's been a leftover after changing code to keep it closer to OP's solution.